# Using Maps SDK for Android in Unity

Tags: unity, android, maps, android-studio

I just started a project on Unity, where I'm a total beginner.

I want to use Google Maps road data from Unity for my mobile game, and I've first looked at using the Maps SDK for Unity. Unfortunately the service is deprecated since 2023.
Since I want the game to be on Android/iOS, how can use the Maps SDK for Android instead? The tutorials I found are only for Android Studio and I'm not sure how to make them works for Unity.

I've also looked at ARCore Geospatial Creator, but I only want road data and this seems a bit overloaded for my needs.

Comment: I would not recommend starting with a maps integration game if you are new to Unity, especially trying to staple together your own replacement for a deprecated service. You will be overwhelmed trying to learn both things at once. The engine is a big enough subject by itself. Start small, making offline games, and learn best practices.